# Trust relationship not working in Windows server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, trust-relationship

**Error**: you don't have proper trust relationship with this workstation.

I have two different forests, XYZ.com and ABC.com. I have made two way trust relationship between these forests with conditional forwarder configured accordingly.
I am facing a problem when I log in through client system,

1. When Client machine belongs to XYZ.com, **I cannot log into ABC.com**
2. When Client machine belongs to ABC.com, **I can log into both ABC.com and XYZ.com**

Type of trust is FOREST type. I checked for all possible mistakes, unable to resolve.
I checked for conditional forwarder in DNS of respective domain controllers, type of trust between forests and transitive or non-transitive trust. Also checked DNS IP of the client w.r.t domain it belonged to.

I am running windows server 2012 on VMware workstation 11.

Comment: Please edit your question to include specifically what you have checked and tried so far to resolve this.

Comment: i checked for conditional forwarder in dns, type of trust relationship, transitivity, alternate dns of client and respective domain controllers.

Comment: Excellent. Please edit your question to include these steps you've taken.